# Error in python code in Choregraphe

Tags: python, error-handling, nao-robot

today I started Choregraphe on my new notebook and I have observed an error I haven't seen yet. The code worked perfectly.

Here is the code:

```
import sys
import time
from naoqi import ALProxy

def main(robotIP):

    PORT = 5058

    try:
        motionProxy = ALProxy("ALMotion",robotIP,PORT)
    except Exception,e:
        print "Could not create proxy to ALMotion"
        print "Error was: "
        sys.exit(1)

    motionProxy.setStiffnesses("Head", 1.0)

    names = "HeadPitch"
    angleLists = 0.349
    timeLists = 1.0
    isAbsolute = True
    motionProxy.angleInterpolation(names,angleLists,timeLists,isAbsolute)

    time.sleep(1.0)

    motionProxy.setStiffnesses("Head",0.0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    robotIP = "192.168.0.20"
    main(robotIP)
```

This code should move head pitch by angle. Yes it worked. The question is: Why is the code showing me this error?

> User class evaluation failed with the error:1

I tried to retype the code or tried to hit "ENTER" at the beginning of the code(on C# works sometimes) but nothing works.

Can someone give me an advice what to do?

Comment: can you post the full traceback?

Comment: sure... "[ERROR] behavior.box :FMBox::createPythonModule:0 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_1289339480__root__Headpitch_2: User class evaluation failed with the error:
<type 'exceptions.SystemExit'>
1"

Comment: I propose that you drop the try/except block that masks the real error. or at least `print "Error was: "+str(e)` or you 're losing the error message.

Comment: tried and makes the same error

Comment: of course, but I need the traceback.

Comment: sry can't make a traceback. I tried but nothing happens

Comment: just do `motionProxy = ALProxy("ALMotion",robotIP,PORT)` without try/except block and post stacktrace.

Comment: WOW sorry for long waiting. I tried to delete try except and i did what you told me... and now it works.. I have no idea why this works now -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the port by 9559. Moreover, there is a new code for naoqi I give you an example :

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding: UTF-8 -*-

import qi
import sys
import argparse



def main(session):
    motionProxy = session.service("ALMotion")

    motionProxy.setStiffnesses("Head", 1.0)

    names = "HeadPitch"
    angleLists = 0.349
    timeLists = 1.0
    isAbsolute = True
    motionProxy.angleInterpolation(names,angleLists,timeLists,isAbsolute)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--ip", type=str, default="127.0.0.1",
                    help="Robot IP address. On robot or Local Naoqi: use '127.0.0.1'.")
    parser.add_argument("--port", type=int, default=9559,
                    help="Naoqi port number")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    session = qi.Session()
    try:
        session.connect("tcp://" + args.ip + ":" + str(args.port))
    except RuntimeError:
        print ("Can't connect to Naoqi at ip \"" + args.ip + "\" on port " + str(args.port) +".\n"
           "Please check your script arguments. Run with -h option for help.")
        sys.exit(1)
    main(session)
```